# PhoneGap jQuery mobile multiple html files css not working

Tags: javascript, android, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have implemented a **Phone Gap application using jQuery Mobile and java script** for iPhone and android.

*My app is almost completed.*

Till now I used **single index.html file for all the pages**.

Now I need to use **`different html files for different pages.`**

So I have created **multiple external html files** for different pages, linked the references and added them in to www folder.

in that the i have a list view its css not visable

[image]

**Main Page:-** See **`page2`** and **`page3`** ref in **index.html** file

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="e" data-header-theme="a" data-dividertheme="a" id="List view">
        <li data-role='list-divider' ><big>Lis view</big></li>
        <li><a href='#page1' id='Page1' data-panel='main'>Page1 Information</a></li>
        <li><a href='page2.html' rel="external" id='pagetwoid' data-panel='main'>Go to Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href='page3.html' rel="external"  id='pagethreeid' data-panel='main'>Go to Page 3</a></li>                             </ul>
</div>
```

**Page2:-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
          <title>Multiple htmls</title>

          <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

          <!--
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.mobile.splitview.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet"  href="inc/jquery.mobile.grids.collapsible.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.mobile.structure-1.0.1.min.css" />
          -->
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.alerts.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="inc/jquery.mobile.datebox.css" />
          <script charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.mobile.splitview.js"></script>


          <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.alerts.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/iscroll-wrapper.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/iscroll-lite.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript">
                           alert('js Loadfed');
               </script>

          <style>
               alert();
               alert('css loaded');

               </style>

     </head>

     <body>


          <!--============= Page2 ===============--->
          <div data-role="page" id="siteContacts" data-theme="e"  >
               <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Page 2 </h1>
                    <a href="page2.html" id="EditButton" data-role="button" data-icon="gear" class="ui-btn-right" data-theme="e" >Edit</a> 
               </div>

                    <div data-role="content">
                         <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview" data-dividertheme="a">

                              <li data-role="list-divider"> <!--list Header --->
                                   <div class="ui-grid-c"> <!--Section Headers Grid--->
                                        <div class="ui-block-a" ><big> aaaa</big> </div>
                                        <div class="ui-block-b" ><big> bbbb</big> </div>
                                        <div class="ui-block-c" ><big> ccc</big> </div>
                                        <div class="ui-block-d" ><big> e-sss</big> </div>
                                   </div>

                              </li>
                              </ul>
                         </div>




     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm reading your code wrong, but it looks like the links to the jquery mobile stylesheets are commented out.  You definitely need to have them defined in the HTML to get the styles applied.

Are you loading them someplace else that it not apparent from the code you posted?

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap requires you to manually set/allow aspects of your app in your "config.xml" file in the root directory.

The solution you are looking for, I believe, is this line:

```
<access origin="http://code.jquery.com" subdomains="true" />
```

You are allowing access to the external resource of "http://code.jquery.com" and allowing all of its subdomains.  This means that you have just unlocked jquery mobile, which is what you are going for, as seen by your script tags:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript" src="inc/jquery.mobile.splitview.js"></script>
> ```
>
> These "src" attributes are now seen as "subdomains" of http://code.jquery.com, which you have just successfully allowed!